# terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::LogicError: Data type mismatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

Suddenly my app started to crash when trying to save something on Realm. I couldn't specifically trace where this error was occurring. Error message:

`terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::LogicError: Data type mismatch`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue is caused when you try to save a realm object, or assign it to another realm object, while it still doesn't have its Primary Key (or any other required key) set.

Explaining better, if you create a realm object and forget to set its Primary Key, when you try to perform a save action (via `addOrUpdateObject` or `commitWriteTransaction`, or any other saving method), or even when you try to relate that object to another realm object (e.g. `chat.message = message`, while `message` doesn't have a PK yet), that exception might be thrown.

To fix this, ensure that every realm object you're creating has its PK and required keys set before saving it.